# function does not evaluate on each occurance

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have a function that does not really evaluate each time.

I have a function that returns a normalisation within a range between -1 and 1. However, if the input is outside a defined range, it will return a larger number.

When i run it, it dont get why it doesent evaluate on each occurance, unless the function is within range

```
 x <- data.frame(c(0.01, -0.01, -0.105, 0.05))


funk <- function(x, mini, maxi) {

temp <-((((x-mini)/(maxi-mini))*2)-1)/100

ifelse( x<= mini, temp <- -10, temp)
ifelse( x>= maxi, temp <- 10, temp)

return(temp)}

x$funk <- funk(x[,1], -0.1, 0.1)
```

I was expecting x$funk = (0.001, -0.001, -10, 0.005)

Answer (score 2):

Its an issue with the way ifelse is written,

`ifelse` is a vectorized function, it evaluates everything in the `true` argument and everything in the `false` argument. It then looks at the indices of the predicate and returns the corresponding true and false values.

```
x <- data.frame(c(0.01, -0.01, -0.105, 0.05))


funk <- function(x, mini, maxi) {

  temp <-((((x-mini)/(maxi-mini))*2)-1)/100

  temp = ifelse( x<= mini, -10, temp)
  temp = ifelse( x>= maxi,  10, temp)

  return(temp)}

x$funk <- funk(x[,1], -0.1, 0.1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, note that the function as presented in the question returns a value between -1/100 and 1/100, if x is between `mini` and `maxi` and does not fill the range between -1 and 1.  If you want the latter remove the 100.  Anyways, using the normalization as written in the question we have the following.

The `ifelse` statements are incorrect.  Try this where the lines marked ## have been changed:

```
funk <- function(x, mini, maxi) {
  temp <-((((x-mini)/(maxi-mini))*2)-1)/100
  temp <- ifelse( x <= mini, -10, temp) ##
  temp <- ifelse( x >= maxi, 10, temp) ##
  return(temp)
}

x$funk <- funk(x[, 1], -0.1, 0.1)
```

### Alternative

An alternative way to write the two `ifelse` statements would be:

```
temp[ x <= mini ] <- -10
temp[ x >= maxi ] <- 10
```

### nested ifelse

This could also be written in nested form:

```
funk2 <- function(x, mini, maxi) {
  ifelse( x <= mini, -10,
    ifelse( x >= maxi, 10, 
      ((((x-mini)/(maxi-mini))*2)-1)/100 
    )
  ) 
}
```

### case_when

Note that the dplyr package has a multi-way analogue to `ifelse` that could be used here:

```
library(dplyr)

funk3 <- function(x, mini, maxi) {
  case_when(
    x <= mini ~ -10,
    x >= maxi ~ 10,
    TRUE ~ ((((x-mini)/(maxi-mini))*2)-1)/100
  )
}
```